# Differentiate shutdowns more than Runtime.setShutdownHook() in Java

Tags: java, exit, shutdown, shutdown-hook

Is there a way to add a shutdown hook that is only fired when the program is shut down because of a System shutdown.

I don't want the code to run when the code finishes regularly, only on other Exits.
With addShutDownHook the Thread runs no matter how the program terminated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a security policy for your program or add a `SecurityManager`.

Then when the `System.exit` is invoked (a regular exit), the `SecurityManager`'s `checkExit` method will be invoked. Inside that method, you can de-register the shutdown hook using `Runtime#removeShutdownHook`.

Comment: You can't unregister a shutdown hook after the shutdown started, but with your method you can coordinate everything over a field

Comment: @lazyguy Inside the shutdown hook there is no portable way to know the reason why the JVM is shutting down.

Comment: Is there an easy way to create a security Manager which by default allows everything, or do you have to Override all the methods with empty ones?

Comment: @lazyguy That's a different topic :) You can look that up or ask a new question.

Comment: @lazyguy after some more thought:
I just added a field in which each thread registers when shutting down properly.  
Then the shutdownHook just checks whether all threads shut down properly. 

This is much easier than using a SecurityManager

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible as of JDK 1.8. At least, I haven't heard of such a mechanism.

Of course, you could add such support yourself using JNI (if the underlying operating system supports it).